# How to turn a .js file into ES6 module when both Webpack and Babel are used?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules, commonjs

As title. I have a file that exposes a top-level/global `var foo`. But I got an error when I ran those production files on Webpack Dev Server, which said that the global variable `foo` is not defined. In the *entry point*(this is a term of Webpack) `.tsx`-file, I've added the following line to import this `.js` file: (I'm sure that the problem is not on the path alias, `@`, and indeed I can omit the `.js`-extension too)

```
import '@/external/path/to/non_es6_module.js'
```

Now I'm reading about this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs, i.e. I think babel is related to this problem. But the sample provided in the link is different than my case, i.e. in my case, there is no `export` in the `.js` file I want to import:

### in

```js
export default 42;
```

### Out

```js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true,
});

exports.default = 42;
```

### Some of my reasoning:

One might say that:

> Why not just modify the `.js`-file, i.e. by adding the `export` keyword, so you can use that Babel plugin to do the transform?

But the problem is that the `.js`-file that I want to import is a **machine-generated** file. And I think it's not ideal to manually modify it, since it will be upgraded in the (near) future. I don't want to do this every time!

Comment: why not explicitly make it global with `window.foo = 42`?

Comment: @Undo: I cannot control/modify the content of the `.js`-file. It's machine-generated and will be updated periodically.